# Rtrim does not work

Tags: php

Help rtrim would not work whatever I do. I also tried to add whitespace after "," like it was on one of the topics i searched here

```
$this->items = array();
$xcount='(';
foreach ($items as $v) {
   $this->items[$v['id']] = $v;
   $xcount.=$v['id'].',';
};
rtrim($xcount, ",");

$xcount.=')';
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `rtrim()` **returns** a value and **does not modify the original value**. Please use it this way:

```
$xcount = rtrim($xcount, ",");
```

From the [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> This function **returns** a string with whitespace (or other characters) stripped from the end of str.

Answer (score -1):

rtrim() for me is not working. I do believe that it is related to the fact that I use greek characters. Check regex instead.

Comment: It works nice. Just need to assign the result to a variable.